# How do I add/remove a list-item onClick using Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onclick, angularjs-ng-click

I am new to Angular.js and what I'm trying to do is adding a lis-item every time the user clicks on `#create-new-rule` but the below doesn't seem to be working.

Also, when the user click on `li .delete` I want that list-item to be removed from the DOM as well as from the `this.rules` array.

app.js

```
app.controller('RuleController', function()
{
    function Rule ()
    {
        this.name = 'untitled';

        this.delete  = function ()
        {
            console.log('removed from DOM as well as from this.rules array');
        };
    };

    this.rules = [];

    this.addRule = function () 
    {
       this.rules.push(new Rule());
    };
});
```

index.html

```
<div id="rule-controller" ng-controller="RuleController as RuleCtrl">

  <ul id="rules">

    <li class="rule" ng-repeat="rule in RuleCtrl.rules">

         <input type="text" ng-value="rule.name"/>    
         <div class="delete" ng-click="rule.delete()">delete</div>

    </li>

  </ul>

  <div id="create-new-rule">
    <div ng-click="RuleCtrl.add()">create new rule</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method for adding is called addRule() but from the view you are calling add(). Try changing that. Furthermore, to remove you can use splice, but you would need to get a reference to `this` outside of the Rule function in order to access the array.

E.g.index.html:

```
<div ng-click="RuleCtrl.addRule()">create new rule</div>
```

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('RuleController', function()
{
    var self = this;
    function Rule ()
    {
        this.name = 'untitled';

        this.delete  = function ()
        {
           var index = self.rules.indexOf(this);
           self.rules.splice(index,1);
        };
    };

    this.rules = [new Rule()];

    this.addRule = function () 
    {
       this.rules.push(new Rule());
    };


});
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great. Also, I realised I was messing up my references with so many `this`.. I see you're using `self` which is great but I've also seen this syntax : `..."someController", function ($scope) {$scope.rules = []; ....etc.});` Is this `$scope` parameter the same as using `this` as a reference to the controller itself ?

Comment: Reinard is using controllerAs syntax instead of $scope. That's the proper way of doing it nowadays. I know it's confusing because there's so many people still using $scope in their bolg posts and tutorials. (They're old.) https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax

Comment: @SproutCoder, tbh, it's up to you what you want to use, but more and more folks are preferring controllerAs above scope. Another article worth reading by John Papa: http://www.johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/